# Can we really predict for distances 100s of light years away?

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light

I read this article today

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/science/8690kmph-winds-discovered-on-exoplanet/articleshow/49789687.cms?utm_source=facebook.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=TOI

The planet is 63 light years far away from earth, is it really possible by the time we are predicting this weather that planet might have vanished ??

The point I want to make is all our prediction on planets 100s of light year away seems so futile because they might now be in a whole different place within universe, when we are doing all this calculations.

Comment: All they're doing is predicting what the weather on the planet was when the light we received from it was emitted.

Comment: Not sure what the question here is - what we're measuring 63 light years away has happened 63 years in the past, who's saying something about "predicting"?

Comment: most plants (if any) do not blow out by themselves  , and the conditions in a planetary system are often predictable enough on those timescales. But true, it is possible that the planet do not exist anymore. Even if it were longer there, the observations still makes us increase our understanding of the universe.

Comment: This isn't about the weather on the planet. You can get a better idea of what is known about it from Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_189733_b

Comment: As far as it being "in a whole different place within the universe" goes, it's not likely that its gone very far in only 63 years. It is orbiting the galaxy just like we are, in the same direction and probably at about the same speed. I'd guess it's "right where we left it," so to speak.

Comment: BTW, they aren't "predicting" the weather; they're "deducing" the weather.

Answer (score 1):

Determining what is happening "right now" on a planet 63 light years away is exactly the same as determining what will be happening 63 years in the future on Earth. Both problems are, technically speaking, impossible. We can't know exactly what the future holds 63 years from now, as things may change in surprising ways, just as we can't know what is happening "right now" on that planet 63 light years away, because nothing (including information) can travel faster than the speed of light.

There's another issue which must be added; in the paragraph above I quotated the phrase "right now", because in General Relatively terms there's no such thing as [universal simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity). "Now" is a relative term, both through time and through space, that depends on the observer.

In addition to these issues, there's nothing cosmologically special about "right now", especially when you aren't talking about billions of years of time. There's just as many [galaxies colliding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interacting_galaxy), [black holes evaporating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation), [planets forming](http://hubblesite.org/hubble_discoveries/discovering_planets_beyond/how-do-planets-form), [Pillars of Creation](https://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/hubble-goes-high-definition-to-revisit-iconic-pillars-of-creation/) collapsing, and [stars going supernova](http://www.universetoday.com/110394/which-star-will-explode-next/) "now" as there were a million years ago, and as there will be a million years in the future.

Add the barriers to knowing about "right now" to the lack of uniqueness of "right now", the convention is to treat the events that we see through our telescopes as happening "right now", even though it may actually have happened many years ago.